# UICollectionViewCell extra padding appears

Tags: ios, uitableview, cocoa-touch, storyboard, uicollectionview

I have made a prototype cell for `UICollectionView` and set some dimension for that. In the cell I have added `Thumbnail`(and other objects) and set `constraints` so that thumnail fills the cell completely. However there is still some space left between. I have set background color in cell to demonstrate that. Attached screenshot for the same. Same thing happens in tableview as well.

One hack could be to set negative value in constraint. But I want to why extra space is coming, even constraint are set to match to cells top, left, bottom, right.
[image: Screenshot of extra padding in UICollectionViewCell]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extra spacing is due to margins, while selecting any constaint just uncheck relative to margin in selected constraints

[image: selct your constraint to edit]

- open second item drop down
- there will be relative to margin and
- uncheck it

Comment: I did not see option to uncheck relative margin in constraints.

Comment: edited my answer I couldn't grab a snapshot of relative margin :(

Comment: relative Margin is default padding btw can you accept this solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Your content of the cell has an x of 8 and y of 8 which will result in having a padding as when you attach a constraint to superviews, the constraints will add as margins. Just change the x and y to 0 and update the constraints!

[EDIT]:

To elaborate the point:

```
1.clear the constraints of the view inside the content view of the cell.
2. make the view's x and y as 0.
3. add constraints as previously, you did, UNCHECK "constraints to margin".
```

[image]

Comment: since my constraint is to match top left of cell, x of 8 and y of 8 is coming as per constraint. If change it to 0,0 it gives warning. To remove warning if i set constraint again, it set constraint to -8,-8. I mentioned samething in my question to put hack of negative constraint. but why extra space if constrain says to match top of image to top of cell. Could not understand it.

Comment: Change your view's x and y as 0, and then put constraints.. uncheck "constraints to margin".